# Selecting a shape

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently working on an Excel tool that I have equipped with one button and one shape-object.

The button is a select button to "select" the shape object. The idea is to Select a shape-object a Picture and change its color after selecting it.

I was able to locate the problem to the clicked Sub of the Select button.

To check if I'm correct I have written a the Macro Select_MyClicked and afterword used the call instruction to invoke the macro from within the Clicked-function of the select button.

```
Sub Select_MyClicked()
Dim ElementName As String
Dim Shp As Object

Set Shp = Sheets("Tabelle1").Shapes(ElementName)
Shp.Select
End Sub

==================================================================
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Call Select_MyClicked
End Sub
==================================================================
```

What is interesting now is:

- When I use the Button the Image is selected but in the Picture format register there i nothing selectable
- If I cklick on the Image itselfe or use the Select_MyClicked Macro indepentently everything in the picture format register is selectable

I also tried to write the select instruction directly into the Button-Clicked private sub. Same result nothing selectable

What I want to do is select an image and change its color. My second question is does somebody know how to open the Colorpennel (with the many colored Rectangles) using vba ?

Comment: Where does the `ElementName` variable get it's value from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally find the solution. It seems like it makes a difference which button you use. In my case it had to be the control elements not the activeX elements

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the `Shape` by its `Name`.  I assigned the name *"myshape"* to the `Shape` before running:

```
Sub Select_MyClicked()
    Dim ElementName As String
    Dim Shp As Shape

    ElementName = "myshape"
    Set Shp = Sheets("Tabelle1").Shapes(ElementName)
    Shp.Select
End Sub
```

The code runs even if `Tabelle1` is not the active sheet.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning it ElementName is referenzed. It is not empty. 
An still by using the button the pictur format register ist exessible but nothing there is selectable. Especially the not the color property. Can you try to use a button an use the call instruction within the private sub click macro to see if it works with your version